# Scrapy not giving output but works in shell

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So i'm new to web scraping and i've been trying to scrape this website but the problem i'm encountering is that when i run my code in shell it runs but it doesn't when i run it as a whole scrapy code.

Here is my Scrapy code block:

```
import scrapy


class MedspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "medspider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.1mg.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.1mg.com/drugs-all-medicines"]

    def parse(self, response):
        meds = response.css('div.style__flex-1___A_qoj')
        
        for med in meds:
            yield{
                'name' : med.css('div div::text').get(),
                'price' : med.css('div:has(> span)::text').getall()[-1],
                'strip content' :  med.css('div::text').getall()[-4],
                'manufacturer' :  med.css('div::text').getall()[-3]
            }
```

Running this code using `scrapy crawl medspider` it gives the following output:-

```
2023-05-28 11:44:22 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.9.0 started (bot: tata1mg)
2023-05-28 11:44:22 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.2.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.8.1, w3lib 2.1.1, Twisted 22.10.0, Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 18:26:48) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 23.1.1 (OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 Mar 2023), cryptography 40.0.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.22624-SP0
2023-05-28 11:44:22 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'tata1mg',
 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tata1mg.spiders',
 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tata1mg.spiders'],
 'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'}
2023-05-28 11:44:22 [asyncio] DEBUG: Using selector: SelectSelector
2023-05-28 11:44:22 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
2023-05-28 11:44:22 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using asyncio event loop: asyncio.windows_events._WindowsSelectorEventLoop
2023-05-28 11:44:22 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 74ffa37a1d23bc25
2023-05-28 11:44:22 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2023-05-28 11:44:22 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2023-05-28 11:44:22 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2023-05-28 11:44:22 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2023-05-28 11:44:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-05-28 11:44:23 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-05-28 11:44:23 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-05-28 11:44:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.1mg.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2023-05-28 11:44:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.1mg.com/drugs-all-medicines> (referer: None)
2023-05-28 11:44:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-05-28 11:44:23 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 896,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 48250,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.670526,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 28, 6, 14, 23, 763883),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 264903,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 2,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 28, 6, 14, 23, 93357)}
2023-05-28 11:44:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

But when i run the code in shell it gives the output like:-

```
In [21]: med.css('div div div ::text').get()
Out[21]: 'Augmentin 625 Duo Tablet'
```

```
In [25]: med.css('div::text').getall()[-4]
Out[25]: 'strip of 10 tablets'
```

```
In [26]: med.css('div::text').getall()[-3]
Out[26]: 'Glaxo SmithKline Pharmaceuticals Ltd'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either in your settings.py file, or using your spiders `custom_settings` attribute, assign a custom `USER_AGENT` value.

For example:

**settings.py**

```
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

or in your spider module:

```
...

class MedspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "medspider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.1mg.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.1mg.com/drugs-all-medicines"]
    custom_settings = {
        "USER_AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }

...
```

And then try running `scrapy crawl ...` again